# I want to store the values(numbers) of the comma separated string in a number array and set all empty values to 0 in C

Tags: c

I want to store all those values in a number array 
Output should be `014182 70 90 0 0` and so on......
I am getting a very funny output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH_OF_NUMBER 9

char *string ;
char *comma ;
char *position ;
char total ;
int scores[42], i, j ;
char number[MAX_LENGTH_OF_NUMBER + 1] ;


int main()
{
    string = "014182,70,90,,,,,89,,69,76,80,,,80,,100,,76,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,90," ;

    comma = strchr (string, ',') ;
    position = string ;
    while (comma) 
    {
        i, j = 0 ;
        while (position < comma) {
            number[i] = *position ;
            i++ ;
            position++ ;
        }
        number[i] = '\0' ;
        position++ ;
        comma = strchr (position, ',') ;        

        scores[j] = atoi (number) ;
        printf("%d\n", scores[j]) ;
        j++ ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output you are getting?

Comment: You shouldn't use global variables if you don't need to use them.

Comment: A good compiler with warnings enabled would say something like "warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]|". Ask yourself why you aren't using a good compiler with warnings enabled, when such compilers are available for free.

Comment: Future reference: Rather than quote "am getting a very funny output", post the funny output.

Comment: Flagging as off-topic due to the lack of MCVE (no actual output)

Answer (score 3):

This is a very big problem:

```
i, j = 0 ;
```

This is actually two distinct expressions, thanks to the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator):

```
i
```

and

```
j = 0
```

The expression `i` is simply ignored, and then you do the assignment of `j`.

I think you want to do

```
i = 0;
j = 0;
```

---

On a somewhat related note, the assignment of `j` at the top of the loop will mean that you will overwrite the same (the first) `scores` entry over and over again.

You should also have some bounds checking so that `j` doesn't get to large.